# Unicode system fonts for ipad

Tags: ipad, unicode, fonts, system

I'd like to essentially create a uilabel with chinese on it. Do I need a unicode font for this, and is there a system font I can use on the iPad? Assuming so, would I need to look up the escape character to denote it if I wanted to simply hardcode it, ie use the \u type of notation? Please assume I'm pretty clueless about unicode, as this question probably implies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a global product/system like this, unicode support is a very basic requirement. iOS device support it natively, including unicode fonts and codepages. No extra effort on this is needed.

For unicode string literals used in source files(I assume XCode here also), I haven't try yet, but my coworkers seems have no problem with it.

Some google results on this you can refer:

- http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/97208-cant-use-utf-8-source-files-false-string-interpretation.html
- http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/224023-unicode-in-constant-nsstrings.html